How can I sort a list of vehicles by maintenance due date in JavaScript?
I'm building a web application to track vehicle maintenance schedules. Each vehicle in my list has a nextMaintenanceDate property, stored as a string in
YYYY-MM-DD 

format. I need to sort this list in ascending order of their maintenance dates to show the upcoming tasks first.
Although I understand how to use JavaScript’s sort() method, I'm unsure of the best approach to handle the date comparison or if there are pitfalls I should watch out for when working with date strings in JavaScript.
I want to sort this list of vehicles in ascending order of their maintenance dates. Here's an example of my data:
const vehicles = [
  { id: 1, name: "Car A", nextMaintenanceDate: "2024-12-10" },
  { id: 2, name: "Car B", nextMaintenanceDate: "2024-12-05" },
  { id: 3, name: "Car C", nextMaintenanceDate: "2024-12-07" }
];

I expect the sorted output to look like this:
[
  { id: 2, name: "Car B", nextMaintenanceDate: "2024-12-05" },
  { id: 3, name: "Car C", nextMaintenanceDate: "2024-12-07" },
  { id: 1, name: "Car A", nextMaintenanceDate: "2024-12-10" }
]

How can I achieve this? Are there any best practices I should follow for sorting by date in JavaScript?

You can combine .sort() with localeCompare() to sort the vehicles list.  This should sort them by their nextMaintenanceData


const vehicles = [
  { id: 1, name: "Car A", nextMaintenanceDate: "2024-12-10" },
  { id: 2, name: "Car B", nextMaintenanceDate: "2024-12-05" },
  { id: 3, name: "Car C", nextMaintenanceDate: "2024-12-07" }
];

vehicles.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.nextMaintenanceDate.localeCompare(b.nextMaintenanceDate);
});

console.log(vehicles);




Kudos for using string compare for lexically sortable timestamps. :-)
